# How to convert a PDF with one long page into a PDF with mutiple A4 pages?

Tags: command-line, pdf, pdftk

I have long PDFs with one page of very large height.

I  want to take each of these PDFs and generate on the Linux/macOS command line a new PDF file from it that is A4-paginated.

I tried using [qpdf](https://qpdf.sourceforge.io/) to do the job, but could find a way to set a target paper-size. Hoe can I do this (with `qpdf` or with another CLI tool like [`pdftk`](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/), etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function is usually called "Poster" (splitting a page into separate pages) qpdf and pdftk usually work at whole page level (like many CLI tools). It can be emulated easily in Acrobat (and others) by simply print the big page media into smaller media pages.

You need tools that are happy to work with partial pages output, and the following 3 cross platform tools, should fill that requirement.

Look at cpdf (community version is free for personal use)
https://github.com/coherentgraphics/cpdf-binaries

I know it is there somewhere but not easy to spot how as its not identified as a single command. John will be very helpful so I recently asked for Windows 32 builds and those were back to health with v2.6.1

Artifex MuTool has a "Poster" command just specify width as one page.
(Not free for commercial use) here is a similar recommendation https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179398

pdfcpu is free for commercial use https://github.com/pdfcpu/pdfcpu
not the same spilt but shows how to call it via bash https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/699457

all should be good enough in one command line.

Comment: Thanks for this. `cpdf` is doing the job for me.